# The meaning of ちゃった in a positive sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice

> こないだ神社で撮った写真. いっぱいいいねもらっ**ちゃった**

This is a sentence that I saw in the subtitles. What is the reason that ちゃった is used here. I know that it used for regret/accidents/completed action, but it seems like something positive happened here.

Comment: Accidents can be positive, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right ちゃう can be used to express an accident or something that is done completely. And usually it's under the context of a negative light, but it doesn't necessarily have to be. It can be used in a positive light too.

いっぱいいいねもらっちゃった can be seen as something like "It (the picture I took) received a ton of likes! (I wasn't expecting that! / Who would have thought this would happen!?)"

Receiving a lot of likes could still be seen as an accident, even though nothing negative happened, because you weren't expecting it to actually happen. Which is indicated by the ちゃう